# Overriding toString method to format Linked List into string recursively

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I need to turn my linked list into a string recursively.  The variable is next Node and variable value is the Node's string value.  The String needs to be formated so that there is a semicolon(with a space before and after) between the values. This is what I have so far..

```
 public String toString() { 
    String result = "";
    if (this.next == null) {//base case
        return " ; " + value;
    }
    else {

        result += this.next.toString() ;//reduction step
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String toString() { 
    String result = value;
    if (next != null) {
        result += " ; " + next.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```